# change bootstrap carousel speed using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Hey guys have you guys ever encountered a carousel that literally goes through the images as fast as it can? lol, I don't want this but its doing it, I have tried the data-interval="10000" but it had no effect. Any help is appreciated thanks.

```
<!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style rel="stylesheet">
/* Carousel*/
        .carousel {
            height: 50%;
        }

    @media (max-width: 776px) {
        .carousel {
            height: 100%;
        }
    }

    .carousel-item,
    .active {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .carousel-inner {
        height: 100%;
    }

    /*Caption*/

    .flex-center {
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>
<!--Carousel Wrapper-->
    <div id="carousel-example-3" class="carousel slide carousel-fade white-text" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="true">
        <!--Indicators-->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-3" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-3" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-3" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!--/.Indicators-->

        <!--Slides-->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

            <!-- First slide -->
            <div class="carousel-item active view hm-black-light" style="background-image: url('http://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/12-col/img%20(11).jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">

                <!-- Caption -->
                <div class="full-bg-img flex-center white-text">
                    <ul class="animated fadeInUp col-md-12">
                        <li>
                            <h1 class="h1-responsive">20 Photos to inspire you to visit Tatra Mountains</h1></li>
                        <li>
                            <p>Best places you should see, traditional dishes that you have to try</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a target="_blank" href="http://mdbootstrap.com/getting-started/" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">See more!</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.Caption -->

            </div>
            <!--/.First slide-->

            <!-- Second slide -->
            <div class="carousel-item view hm-black-light" style="background-image: url('http://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(67).jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">

                <!-- Caption -->
                <div class="full-bg-img flex-center white-text">
                    <ul class="animated fadeInUp col-md-12">
                        <li>
                            <h1 class="h1-responsive">10 Reasons you should spend winter holiday in mountains </h1>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p>Best atractions and winter sports!</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a target="_blank" href="http://mdbootstrap.com/bootstrap-tutorial/" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Read more</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.Caption -->

            </div>
            <!--/.Second slide -->

            <!-- Third slide -->
            <div class="carousel-item view hm-black-light" style="background-image: url('http://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(97).jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">

                <!-- Caption -->
                <div class="full-bg-img flex-center white-text">
                    <ul class="animated fadeInUp col-md-12">
                        <li>
                            <h1 class="h1-responsive">Weekend in the nature - the best way to relax</h1></li>
                        <li>
                            <p>8 Reasons why you need to spend more time in nature</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a target="_blank" href="http://mdbootstrap.com/forums/forum/support/" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Read more</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.Caption -->

            </div>
            <!--/.Third slide-->
        </div>
        <!--/.Slides-->

        <!--Controls-->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example-3" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example-3" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
        <!--/.Controls-->
    </div>
    <!--/.Carousel Wrapper-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this jquery--

```
$('#carousel-example-3').carousel({
interval: 10000
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it did! however I needed to use this
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
})
Thank you for your input!